# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | bigint'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having an error with formatting this API data, the weird part is that it is console logging the response I want, and the format is number.

Does anyone know why typescript is not accepting this and what may be causing this issue ?

**Code**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import api from '../../services';

import { CardsList, Value } from './styles';

interface ContractProps {
  data: {
    dataCards: {
      billing: {
        monthlyBilling: number;
      };
    }
  }
}

const Cards: React.FC = () => {
  const [contract, setContract] = useState<ContractProps>();
  const monthlyBillingData = contract?.data.dataCards.billing.monthlyBilling;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    api.get('').then(response => {
      setContract(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
  
  console.log(monthlyBillingData);
  console.log(typeof(monthlyBillingData));
  console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(monthlyBillingData));

  return (
      <CardsList>
          <h3>Ativos</h3>
          <Value>
            <strong>R$ {contract?.data.dataCards.billing.monthlyBilling}</strong>
          </Value>
      </CardsList>
  );
};

export default Cards;
```

**Error**

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(value: number | bigint): string', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | bigint'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | bigint'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(value: number): string', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.  TS2769

    28 |   console.log(monthlyBillingData);
    29 |   console.log(typeof(monthlyBillingData));
  > 30 |   console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(monthlyBillingData));
       |                                              ^
    31 | 
    32 | 
    33 |   return (
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
handleErrors @ webpackHotDevClient.js:174
push../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:213
index.tsx:28 100000
index.tsx:29 number
index.tsx:30 100,000
```

**API**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The optional chaining (`?.`) operator here will give `undefined` if `contract` is nullish:

```
contract?.data.dataCards.billing.monthlyBilling
        ^
```

You need to decide what you want to render and/or what you want to log in such a case, in a type-safe way. This depends on the logic you wish to implement.

Note that this:

```js
new Intl.NumberFormat().format(undefined)
```

Returns the string `"NaN"`, which is unlikely to be useful (to the extent that TypeScript assumes it isn't what you want).